# Rebasing Kernel into High Memory

Tags: assembly, kernel

How do I rebase a custom operating-system kernel into high memory, so that the address `0xABCD` becomes `0xFFFFFF800000ABCD`? (The kernel has already been loaded starting at address `0x100000` by the boot loader.) My current solution generates page faults on addresses that weren’t mapped, which escalates into a triple fault because the IDT has not yet been initialized.

Comment: Why does it matter? If you are going to have an OS with a map, just put it in its own space whereever that is convenient.  If it already loads real addresses 001xxxxx, and sets up a map that maps physical 001xxxxx to virtual 01xxxxxx, then it should be able to make the transition of real to virtual without any other shenanigans.  If you want to then replicate the OS pages at virtual 0xFFFFFF... all you need to do is modify the memory map, but once you are this far, I don't see much point.

Answer (score 1):

Don't explicitly move your kernel.

Instead, use paging. First, set up everything in low memory, then enable paging and map (not move) the kernel high. No copying of bytes involved.